# Dovecot and UPDATE MySQL query

Tags: mysql, dovecot

I need to know what the boxes do not use e-mail and delete them.
I wanted to change dovecot-sql.conf:

```
UPDATE users SET last_=NOW() WHERE username = '%u'
```

but the result is "0"
Help me. tnx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I`m found this and it`s working http://wiki1.dovecot.org/PostLoginScripting